Problem with uname -r on VPS server
I'm trying to install amneziawg (wireguard) on VPS server with debian 11
When it starting I get this error
Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for awg0...  
[#] ip link add awg0 type amneziawg  
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported  
Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported  
[#] ip link delete dev awg0 
Cannot find device "awg0" 
awg-quick@awg0.service:  Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

During installation there was one command I couldn't do
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r):
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.0 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.0' 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.19.0'

(I did reboot)
Some commands I've tried:
sudo modprobe amneziawg:
modprobe: FATAL: Module amneziawg not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0

uname -a:
Linux example.com 4.19.0 #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 12:00:44 MSK 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dir /lib/modules/:
4.19.0  5.10.0-33-amd64  5.10.0-33-rt-amd64

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.10.0-33-amd64:
linux-headers-5.10.0-33-amd64 is already the newest version (5.10.226-1). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

As you might have guessed, I have no idea what I'm doing or how to resolve this issue.
It seems to me that problem is with 4.19.0 modules folder
Can I somehow switch it to 5.10.0 version if it's NAT VPS service?
It probably has one kernel for every virtual server or something like that...
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot

Doesn't do anything
What do I do? Any suggestions are welcome.

Your VPS is likely not a full blown virtual machine, but a container on some host system. All containers on the host system share the same kernel, the host kernel, so there's no point trying to build a kernel module, you won't be able to load it.
If you want to use wireguard, you're best bet is to use a userspace implementation. wireguard-go is packaged in Debian.
